# expected ‘struct CELLULE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct CELLULE’

Tags: c

Hello guys i hope all of you are fine,

i'm here for search some help because , i have a little problem, when i trying to compile my program i have an error in function main at this line d = DEPILER(*p);

the error is

```
main.c:12:19: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘DEPILER’
        p = DEPILER(*p);
               ^
In file included from Indexation.h:4:0,
             from base.h:1,
             from main.c:3:
PileID.h:18:9: note: expected ‘struct CELLULE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct CELLULE’
 Pile_ID DEPILER (Pile_ID *p);
     ^
main.c:14:21: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘DEPILER’
     }while( DEPILER(*p) != NULL);
                 ^
In file included from Indexation.h:4:0,
             from base.h:1,
             from main.c:3:
PileID.h:18:9: note: expected ‘struct CELLULE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct CELLULE’
 Pile_ID DEPILER (Pile_ID *p);
     ^
Makefile:12 : la recette pour la cible « main.o » a échouée
make: *** [main.o] Erreur 1
```

i search a lot to find why my program don't work but i don't know because the argument of

> d = DEPILER(*p);

is

> *p

of type

> Pile_ID

and my prototype of DEPILER is

> identifiant DEPILER (Pile_ID *p);

so why he want an argument of the type

> struct CELLULE **

// my main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "base.h"

int main(){

    Pile_ID p;
    identifiant d;

    p = Indexation("/home/mallent/FICHIER_PROJET/Textes");
    do{
      d = DEPILER(*p);
      //Copie(*d);
    }while( DEPILER(*p) != NULL);
}


// function depiler in file PileID.c

identifiant DEPILER (Pile_ID *p){
    assert(PILE_EST_VIDE);
    identifiant x;
    Pile_ID paux;
    paux=(*p)->suiv;
    x.d=(*p)->ID.d;
    x.titre=(*p)->ID.titre;
    free (*p);
    (*p)=paux;
    return x;
}


// function depiler in file PileID.h
#include "descripteur.h"
typedef struct etIdentifiant{
    descrip d;
    const char *titre;
}identifiant;

typedef struct CELLULE{
    identifiant ID;
    struct CELLULE *suiv;
}Cel;

typedef struct CELLULE * Pile_ID;
```

PS : Sorry for my english i hope you will understand thanks for all people who will try to help me (^_^)

Comment: `DEPILER(*p);` --> `DEPILER(&p);`

Answer (score 1):

Try `d = DEPILER(&p);` instead of `d = DEPILER(*p);`.

Comment: thanks i just forgot that i need to give an adress to DEPILER ^^